# Laravel Eloquent related model must match two foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using eloquent in laravel framework. I would like to get the models from table D that are related to table A via BOTH table B and table C.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is situation in database:
[image]

This is the sample data for the database:

```
INSERT INTO A (idA) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO A (idA) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO A (idA) VALUES(3);

INSERT INTO B (idB, A_idA) VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO B (idB, A_idA) VALUES(2, 2);

INSERT INTO C (idC, A_idA) VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO C (idC, A_idA) VALUES(2, 2);
INSERT INTO C (idC, A_idA) VALUES(3, 3);

INSERT INTO D (idD, B_idB, C_idC) VALUES(1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO D (idD, B_idB, C_idC) VALUES(2, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO D (idD, B_idB, C_idC) VALUES(3, 2, 3);
```

Here are the models:

```
class A extends Model
{
    protected $table = "A";
    protected $primaryKey = "idA";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function B()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\B", "A_idA");
    }

    public function C()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\C", "A_idA");
    }
}

class B extends Model
{
    protected $table = "B";
    protected $primaryKey = "idB";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function D()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\D", "B_idB");
    }

    public function A()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\A", "A_idA");
    }
}

class C extends Model
{
    protected $table = "C";
    protected $primaryKey = "idC";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function D()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\D", "C_idC");
    }

    public function A()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\A", "A_idA");
    }
}

class D extends Model
{
    protected $table = "D";
    protected $primaryKey = "idD";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function B()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\B", "B_idB");
    }

    public function C()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\C", "C_idC");
    }
}
```

Here is the controller

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        $aWithRelatedDs = A::with(['B.D'])->whereHas("B.D")->whereHas("C.D")->get();
        dd($aWithRelatedDs);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Collection {#380 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => A {#390 ▶}
    1 => A {#388 ▼
      #table: "A"
      ... snip ...
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "B" => Collection {#387 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => B {#398 ▼
              #table: "B"
              ... snip ...
              #relations: array:1 [▼
                "D" => Collection {#395 ▼
                  #items: array:2 [▼
                    0 => D {#407 ▼
                      #table: "D"
                      ... snip ...
                      #attributes: array:3 [▼
                        "idD" => 2
                        "B_idB" => 2
                        "C_idC" => 2
                      ]
                      ... snip ...
                    }
                    1 => D {#408 ▼
                      #table: "D"
                      ... snip ...
                      #attributes: array:3 [▼
                        "idD" => 3
                        "B_idB" => 2
                        "C_idC" => 3
                      ]
                      ... snip ...
                    }]}]
... snip ...
```

The problem: A #2 does not have two D associated via both B and C, it only has D #2 associated via both intermediate tables, but in the result above it is listed anyway. How can I limit this, so both associations must be to the same model?

Comment: Please post the code you already tried it with.

Comment: Two whereHas is the correct way. You're doing it wrong

Comment: @Namoshek I added the code. Thank you.

Comment: @devk Must be something obvious I don't see.

Comment: Oh, they must be associated to the same model D. That changes it. I'm not sure 2 whereHas are the way to go then. How about something like `A::whereHas('b.d.c')->get()`. Noted that I'm not sure if dot notation works in `whereHas`, just assumed it does from your example

Comment: Are you querying for `A` or for `D`? You describe that you want `D`, but you showed a dump for `A`...

Comment: @Namoshek I would like to get A and for each A I would like to access D that is related to A via both tables, if such thing is even possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all `A` that have at least one `D` which is connected to `A` through both `B` and `C`, then the raw SQL query would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT D.id
  FROM D
    INNER JOIN B ON D.b_id = B.id
    INNER JOIN C ON D.c_id = C.id
  WHERE B.a_id = A.id
    AND C.a_id = A.id
)
```

I also prepared an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25449a/6) for this.

My advice would be to create a new relation on `A` which finds all `D` through `B`, for which we find a `C` that is also connected back to `A`. Sounds weird, but is quite easy and looks like this:

```
public function doubleLinkedDs(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(D::class, B::class)
        ->whereHas('C', function ($q) {
            $q->where('a_id', $this->id);
        });
}
```

By the way, this expects that you have proper relationships set up. But as far as I can see from the question, this should be fine.

If we have the relationship defined, we should be able to perform the following, very simple query:

```
A::has('doubleLinkedDs')
    ->with('doubleLinkedDs')
    ->get();
```